# React Redux Material-ui - Making a table with editable cells

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am fairly new to material-ui, I assume my question may have a simple answer but I just wanted to get some feedback. What I would like to do is render a table with only column headers (populated from data stored in a database). At this point there should be no rows. Ideally I would then like to have a clickable button that can add a row (with the same number of cells as column headers) which data can then be entered in to and saved to the database. I assume I can add the onCellClick attribute to make it possible to enter data into the cells of the material-ui table, but my big question is what would be the best way to generate the rows? Previously I did something similar to this by just pushing an object into an empty array, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this? Especially considering that one of the main reasons I decided to build this with React and Redux was to try and avoid doing something like this!

Anyway thanks for your time, if you could show me an example of a better way I might do this then that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using Material-UI's Table tag by populating the cells of the table with components that are editable (drop downs, text fields, etc.). However, I've stopped using it for larger data sets because it was not performant. Instead, I use [ReactDataGrid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/). It's a little bit tricky to get the CSS right to look good with Material-UI but it's much more performant. I populate the cells in ReactDataGrid with Material-UI components just as you can with Material-UI's Table.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, as the tables I will be eventually generating will range from small datasets to very large datasets. Ok so the best thing for me to do is to is add a row of empty material-ui components (text fields or something similar) and then save the changes? I don't know if you have much experience with this but is what I mentioned in the original question the best way to add the row of is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Yep, just add it to the row. [Here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/material-ui-template/blob/master/src/app/components/AdvancedTable.jsx) is an example of doing just that. It's a wrapper of MUI's Table to allow you to pass in an array, a config object and components to instantiate on each row. It's way more complicated than you want but I don't have time to work up a more simple answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again